# ruby on rails- Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new with ruby on rails and im trying to follow that tutorial : [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm)

when I tried to run mysql I got error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I didn't understand how should I run those command:

```
mysql> create database library_development;
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on library_development.*
to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I will be happy for some help.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your database configuration is wrong. In the database.yml you should set the right login and password.